# Taking a string and removing commas from it, vb6, SQL?

Tags: sql, listview, vb6

So I have a listview in my application. I let the user select multiple items from it, and save it in SQL-SERVER. If more than one items are selected, i save the values as string in this format 105, 106, 107. Now I need to Select these values and remove the commas from them, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and the comment to the answer from Mat I would say forget removing the comma's and use `Split`

```
   Dim strArray() As String
   Dim intCnt As Integer


   strArray = Split(strYourCommaDelimitedData, ",")

   For intCnt = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
      'Trim(strArray(intCnt)) or CInt(Trim(strArray(intCnt)) 
      'will hold each value use it to select your item
   Next
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SERVER you could use REPLACE:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(YourData,',','') from YourDataset
```

This would replace the comma as required.

Comment: That sounds like a fine idea. My problem is this...I'm saving these values as a string with commas, how would I convert it back to a value and make it selected in a listview??